# call a method from server

Tags: java, client-server

client1.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class client1 {
   public static void main (String [] args) {

       Socket connectToServer;
       OutputStream out;
       BufferedReader in;
       String msg;
       String result;

       try {
            connectToServer = new Socket ("localhost", 5555);
            out = connectToServer.getOutputStream ( );

            in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (connectToServer.getInputStream ( )));

            msg = "sum" + "\n";

            out.write (msg.getBytes ( ), 0, msg.length ( ));
            msg = "5" + "\n";

            out.write (msg.getBytes ( ), 0, msg.length ( ));
            result = in.readLine ( );

            System.out.println (result);

            connectToServer.close ( );
      } catch (Exception ex) {System.out.println (ex);}
   }
}
```

server1.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class server1 {
   public static void main (String [] args) {

       ServerSocket c;
       Socket cs;
       OutputStream out;
       BufferedReader in;
       String msg;
       String name;
       int parameter;
       int result=0;

       try {
            c = new ServerSocket (5555);
            cs = c.accept ( );

            out = cs.getOutputStream ( );
            in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (cs.getInputStream ( )));

            name = in.readLine( );

            parameter = Integer.parseInt (in.readLine ( ));

            result = name(parameter);
            out.write (result.getBytes ( ), 0, result.length ( ));                

        } catch (Exception ex) {System.out.println (ex);}
    }

    static int sum (int n)
    {
        return (n + 5);
    }
}
```

I want to call a sum method from a server and I excepted from server to back the result of function but there are some bugs I'm really tired from it need some help my friends

sorry for my bad English

Comment: What is the error ? what is the question ?

Comment: if you want to call the method directly from the client, not just receiving the result, you should consider using [RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/) instead of sockets.

Comment: @niculare but I want to recev the result by using sockets

Comment: then you should call the method on the server and then send the result to the client through socket. you cannot call a method from server by using sockets.

Comment: @niculare Yes I know that but there is an error when I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is not complete.

```
result = name(parameter);
```

This line of code calls a method named `name`.  It does not look up a method using the value of the variable `name`.

```
int result=0;
// [...]
out.write (result.getBytes ( ), 0, result.length ( ));
```

Here you try to use String methods on an int.

---

*Corrections:*

In your server you need to process the message so that you can choose the correct method to call.  Additionally, you need to handle processing the text of your protocol to convert it to the proper Java types and vice versa.  Specifically, you need to call `Integer.parseInt()` to convert the `String` from the protocol to the `int` required by your `sum()` method.  Then you need to format the `int` returned as a `String` so you can send it back to your client.

Eg.

```
if ("sum".equals(name))
    {
    // TODO: catch NumberFormatException and handle bad input
    final int parameter_value = Integer.parseInt(parameter);
    result = sum(parameter_value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In line 21 you are writing the `msg` string "sum\n" to the server.

The server received the `msg` in its line 23 ans stores it in the `name` variable.
Currently, `name` is a String object, so trying to run `name(someString)` won't work unless preceded by `new`.

Your best bet is to use an if statement to check for which method is called, then run that method, so:

```
if (name.equals("sum")) {
    result = sum(parameter);
    out.write (result.getBytes ( ), 0, result.length ( )); 
}
```

You could even use a switch statement if you're going to have more methods besides `sum`.

You can use the Java reflection API to dynamically invoke methods on a class. However, since Java is a compiled language, local variables' (within methods, constructors, parameters, etc) information is erased on compilation. However you still have complete access to class names, hierarchies, methods and fields (class variables).
A good starting point is the [Reflection API tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) or the getClass() method of Object. However this is probably beyond the scope of what you want to do.